# Efficient way to structure falcor router for deep paths?

Tags: falcor, falcor-router

I'm continuing my [experiments](https://github.com/tivac/falcor-experiment) with falcor and enjoying most of it, but I'm noticing something concerning.

I'm assembling my JSONGraph from multiple disparate APIs, exactly what `falcor-router` is intended to do. However I can't seem to find a way to cleanly provide a catch-all for fields that don't need special handling w/o blowing up any routes that **do** need to do special handling.

My routes look something like the following:

- `items[{integers:ids}].name`
- `items[{integers:ids}][{keys:fields}]`

No matter the order I declare the routes in the generic one always wins. Is there a better way to avoid this than the full-nuclear option of structuring my routes like this?

- `items[{integers:ids}].name`
- `items[{integers:ids}]['fooga', 'wooga', 'booga', 'tooga', ... ]`

That seems very brittle, if the data coming from the backing server changes I have to update not only my application code but my router as well. It also becomes a real mess if you have deeply nested objects as the number of permutations climb in a hurry.

Comment: Fixed, this was indeed a bug. https://github.com/Netflix/falcor-router/pull/139

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a bug. The router should match the most specific path first. I would appreciate if you could log it as an issue. We will fix it for you.

Comment: [Filed](https://github.com/Netflix/falcor-router/issues/125), let's see what happens!